# Accessing a module's action rendered output

Tags: yii

I'm writing an "Account" module which should take care of everything about accounts: registration, login/logout, user administration, password recovery, account activation, etc.

So I thought it would be best to reuse whatever the module's DefaultController::actionRegister() generates to show on the main page.

So my question is: how to create a new "sub request" (similar to CController::forward()) from any controller (either SiteController, read: from views/layouts/main.php, or another controller, eventually of another submodule) to a given module/controller/action?

I've tried with $this->forward() from within my application layout without success: it shows a blank page, no error whatsoever.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to [make a widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/basics.view#widget). Avoiding tightly coupled classes and actions will make your application more secure, easier to maintain and improve and far more reusable.

"Inline partial redirects" are never the answers to any question, at least in Yii.